# Outlook - Creating a rule to forward emails based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to create an outlook rule that says -

- For all the emails I receive
- After 5pm to 8am on Weekdays
- Anytime during the weekends
- Except for emails I receive from @mycompany
- Send to a mailbox

Basically I can move all of my emails except the ones I get from @mycompany but looks like its client side. So if my outlook isn't open, these emails will just sit in my inbox. I need to be able to have this server side.

Also, I can't figure out how to do after 5pm to 8am Weekdays and anytime during the Weekends.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the email header you get the time stamp: *example: "Mon 9/9/2019 9:41 AM*". With that in mind, to create desired rules, You can take advantage of the "**Message header includes**" or "**with specific words in the message header**" parameter.

I'm assuming that You/your company is using ISP email, or have private email servers based on SMTP & IMAP/POP3. If so, You have two options:

**First:** Ask Your IT Sys admin to setup your Rules on Outlook/Thunderbird inside the always on VM with rules like this (I have created these inside "Outlook.Live.com", but they are easily replicated inside Outlook App):

- Rule for the WeekDays:

[image]

- Rule for the Weekend:

[image]

**Second:** Forward all your emails to your outlook acc (*create one*) and there(inside the browser) create above mentioned rules for your emails with necessary tweaks. Plus on top of that, You will need some rules inside Outlook on your maschine for housekeeping, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks ill talk to them to see if this is possible!!

Answer (score 0):

Get similar information from [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb3f0688-f809-43ee-9131-9f20840f6c9a/out-of-office-at-the-wish-of-an-user?forum=outlook), in the email header, you will get the time stamp of the email. Create the rule based on the "with specific words in the message header".

You may refer to this:

1. Anytime during the weekends

   [image]
2. After 5pm to 8am on Weekdays

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if nothing ill have to create rules for all the employees.